# Representing $C(X)$ as multiplication operators on $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and I represent $C(X)$ isometrically in $B(L^p(X,\mu))$ as multiplication operators for some finite positive regular Borel measure $\mu$. If I remember correctly, if $X$ is a compact metric space, then I may take $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite (?). For a general compact Hausdorff space, is there any property that I can assume for $\mu$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course we must be talking about *Borel* measures, so that continuous functions are measurable.

If $X$ is a compact metric space, or in fact any separable compact Hausdorff space, you can take $\mu$ to be a *finite* measure. If $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is dense, let $$\mu=\sum 2^{-n}\delta_{x_n}.$$

In general it took me a minute to see that there even *exists* such a measure. But of course counting measure on $X$ always works. Is there any property you can assume in general? That's broad enough that presumably the answer is yes. But you can't take $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite in general.

I think it's clear that $\mu$ works if and only if for every nonempty open set $V$ there exists $E\subset V$ with $0<\mu(E)<\infty$. In any case, it's certainly clear that if $x$ is an isolated point of $X$ you need $0<\mu(\{x\})<\infty$. There exist compact Hausdorff spaces with uncountably many isolated points, for example $X=[0,\omega_1]$, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal.

And in fact considering $[0,\alpha]$ for larger ordinals $\alpha$ you see that for any cardinal $\kappa$ you cannot assume that $X$ is the union of fewer than $\kappa$ sets of finite measure.